# Expand OS Partition inside Extended partition

Tags: linux, windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning

Originally Win7 --> dual booted with Ubuntu 20.04. Shrunk win partition and want to grow Linux into that unallocated space but no luck. Tried everything incl booting from usb Ubuntu 19 and easus from win7... Any help appreciated thanks!

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk model: KINGSTON SUV400S
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x75198513

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       206848  55609343  55402496 26.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        55609344 234440703 178831360 85.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       142790656 234440703  91650048 43.7G 83 Linux

$ sudo parted -l

Model: ATA KINGSTON SUV400S (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      106MB   28.5GB  28.4GB  primary   ntfs         boot
 2      28.5GB  120GB   91.6GB  extended
 5      73.1GB  120GB   46.9GB  logical   ext4
```

[image: GParted screenshot]

Comment: What have you tried exactly? What was the problem you've encountered?

Comment: Here is my gparted screen [url=https://postimg.cc/WdgGBmhR][img]https://i.postimg.cc/WdgGBmhR/gparted.png[/img][/url]

Comment: I've tried to grow sda5 into the unused portion of the extended partition using gparted, growpart etc as superuser, tried easus from Win7, tried booting in Ubuntu OS on USB. Nothing lets me grow sda5 into unused space.

Answer (score 0):

The partition in your GParted screenshot is locked - most likely because it's mounted, because you've tried to browse it before opening GParted. Right-click it and select *Unmount*. Then you can resize it. Don't forget to click the *Apply* button!

As always before operating on partitions, **make sure your backups are up to date first**. This particular operation will involve rewriting entire partition (filesystems can't be grown left). Interruption may leave the partition in unusable state.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me. I tried to Unmount, but it won't let me. Says Target is busy. I quit gparted, then closed all windows and reopened gparted, but it still says busy. This the partition I'm running on

Comment: You have to boot from USB. You can't move a partition you're booting from.

Comment: Thanks for your patient help :) This worked perfectly!